# the "observable" space of a measure space

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory, entropy

For a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, the space of "observables" with respect to finite set $F$ which is endowed with counting measure on all of its subsets, is defined as follows:

$$obs (X, \mu, F)=\{f:X\to F \,|\, f  \,\,\text{is measurable}\}.$$

$obs(X, \mu, F)$ With metric $d$ which measures the points of difference of two functions is a metric space:

$$d(f, g)=\mu \{x|f(x) \neq g(x)\}. $$

My questions are:

1- where the term "observable" comes from and why?

2- Which connections may I expect from this correspondence, by correspondence I mean corresponding a metric space $obs(X, \mu, F)$ to a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, and which connection exists?

**PS:**

- For clearing the question 2, I must explain some more details. $(obs(X, \mu, F), d)$ is a compact metric space (It is compact because pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable). Now my new question is:
  2': When I must expect for observables space be a geodesic metric space and which geometric properties of this space relates to measure theoretic properties of the space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$?
- As @michael-greinecker 's mentioned, considering the finite set $F$ with counting measure is not important for measurability of observables.

Comment: Question 1: if you think of $X$ as the set of states of a physical system, or the set of possible outcomes of an experiment, then any function on $X$ is an "observable" quantity that returns different values depending on the state the system is in. Question 2: unclear what you are asking.

Comment: These observables are nothing else than what is commonly called "finite measurable partitions" - which are widely used in ergodic theory.

Comment: @NikWeaver you are right, my second question is unclear, but I don't mean any functoriality because if it is then it is a poor one. This correspondence appears in ergodic theory specially in definition of entropy. I must add a PS to clear my question.

Comment: @RW Yes, but I expect a physical interpretation which Nik explained somewhat.

Comment: Where does counting measure on subsets of $F$ come in?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker the counting measure in my question is a wasted information, sorry. Because my question only nead measurability of observables and in addition, the metric is defined by measure $\mu$ on $X$.

Comment: In general, $d$ is not a metric because $d(f,g)=0$ does not imply $f=g$.

Comment: @jochen-wengenroth Like in real analysis we always work with such spaces up to almost everywhere equality.

Answer (score 1):

The space of observables is typically not compact when $|F| > 1$. For example, if $|F| = 2$ and $X$ is a nonatomic probability space then the space of observables can be identified with the measure algebra of $X$.

Futhermore, any two nonatomic standard probability spaces are isomorphic and hence under this assumption on $X$ the space of observables depends only on the cardinality of $F$.

Comment: For any set $X$ and finite set $F$, the topological space $F^{X}$ with product topology which is pointwise convergence, is a compact space (Tychonoff's theorem). But measurable elements if this space is a closed subset so is compact.

Comment: @Shakiba, burtonpeterj is right. (The set of measurable elements is typically not closed.)

Comment: @nik-weaver For finiteness of $F$, any convergent sequence of measurable, $f_{n}$, which is convergent to a function $f$, when is computed in a point must be ultimately constant so there is a &n& such that $f_{n}=f$, thus $f$ is measurable. Am I wrong?

Comment: @nik-weaver oops! my reasoning was incorrect. Let me try a different reasoning: 

measurability of $f$ means $f^{-1} (a)$ is measurable for any $a \in F$ but when a sequence of measurable functions $f_{n}$ converges to $f$, $f^{-1}(a)=\{x \in X | \exists N, \forall n \geq N, x \in f_{n}^{-1}(a)\}$. Latest equality is nothing but $\bigcup_{k=1} \bigcap_{n=k}f_{n}^{-1}(a)$ which is measurable. So this is a proof for: pointwise limit of measurable observable is a measurable one.

Comment: Actually, that isn't right. It only shows that the limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable. The limit of a net won't be, in general. And anyway the metric topology is different from the product topology.

Comment: It is not true that "any two nonatomic probability spaces are isomorphic", not even in terms of their measure algebra.

Comment: I should have assumed that the probability spaces are standard.